# Is it possible to specify aggregate code coverage testing when deploying with a list of tests to Salesforce

Tags: deployment, ant, salesforce

I am automating deployment and CI to our Salesforce orgs using Ant. In my build xml, I am specifying the complete list of our tests to run. Salesforce is returning code coverage errors, demanding 75% code coverage on a per file basis rather than allowing only 75% based on the total code base. Some of our old files do not have that level of coverage, and I am trying not to have to go back and create a ton of new tests for old software.

It seems like Salesforce is doing the code coverage based on the quickdeploy model, rather that the aggregate.

Does anyone know a way I can tell Salesforce not to use the quickdeploy model (if that is what it is doing). I have checked the Migration tool docs, but don't see anything.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the attribute `runAllTests="true"` inside the `sf:deploy` tasks, rather than listing each test out?

Comment: Yes, I can't use that option because then it runs Managed Package Tests in my sandboxes and that creates test failures. If the sandboxes worked the same as production I would be golden, but for some reason they behave differently than when deploying to our production org.